# How can a member method in an std::map when I want specific parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am attempting to build a fsm using a map which contains actions.  I am trying to bind the next state to the action but it doesn't seem to work as expected.  A simplified example follows.

I have an enumeration for all the states that this fsm will use:

```
typedef enum
{
    init,
    query,
    anotherState
} State;
```

I have a class that contains my action methods.

```
class MyClass
{   
    protected:
    void BuildStateMap();
    void StateEngine();

    private:
    void Init(State nextState);
    void Query(State nextState);
    State state;
    std::map<State, std::function<void(State)>> stateMap;
```

I have a method for building the state map.

```
MyClass::BuildStateMap()
{
    state = init;
    map[init] = std::bind(&MyClass::Init, this, query);
    map[query] = std::bind(&MyClass::Query, this, anotherState);
    ...
}
```

An implementation of the action might look like this:

```
void MyClass::Init(State nextState)
{
    DoStuff();
    state = nextState;
}
```

An implementation of the StateEngine might look like this:

```
void MyClass::StateEngine()
{
    auto itr = stateMap.find(state);
    if (itr != stateMap.end())
    {
        itr->second();  // I think this should call Init() with the parameter query that was "bound" to it in the std::bind call above.
    }
}
```

So why when I call itr->second();  Do I get an error like this:

```
no match for call to '(std::function<void(State)>)()'
```

when I would expect this to automatically pass the state query as the parameter.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: just a quick note: there's no need for the `typedef` on your `enum`, this is just an artifact from `C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are including a value for the `State` parameter in the binding itself, the map should be to type `std::function<void()>`.

If you wanted to pass the `State` at call time instead of bind time, then you could leave the map as it is, but you'd need to use `itr->second(whateverStateShouldBePassed)`. This would also require you to do the binding as `std::bind(&MyClass::Init, this, std::placeholders::_1)`.

Note that lambdas often provide a more convenient syntax than `bind` in situations like this, though it's largely a matter of taste:

```
stateMap<State, std::function<void()>> map;
map[init] = [=]() { Init(query); };
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think the lambda might be the better option.  It's more succinct and more readable.